# WPF organizing data templates

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm writing a WPF application. I want it to display data in ListBox from different sources. I want to make some common source interface like

```
interface IDataSource<T>
{
   ObservableCollection<T> Elements { get; set; }
   DataTemplate ElementDataTemplate { get; set; }
}
```

But I don't know which is the best type or types which I should user for `IDataSource`. I can make it `UserControl`, but it seems to be unnecessary, because my `DataSource` is not user control. The main problem is with `ElementDataTemplate`. How can I properly manage it not from `UserControl` class? Should I care another helper `UserCntrol` class and call something like (`new MyUserControl).FindResource("ElementsDataTemplate")` to obtain datatemplate or there is more fine way to keep and get `DataTemplate`?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply apply a data template for a specific type in the resource section of the corresponding view:

```
<!-- Items may be of type ViewModel1 and ViewModel2 -->
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ViewModel1}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyA}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ViewModel2}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyB}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

So there is no need for the interface.

Comment: I don't know how many sources (viewModels) there will be, so I want each source keep Datatemplate in itself.